TV series about youth with super human powers
I am searching for an English language TV series. Could be an Australian one but I am leaning towards American. This is definitely before 2000. I watched it when I was a kid on a state run television so scenes are somewhat blurred.
It is about a college kid (age 16-19) with super human powers. 
I remember in one episode there's this college football team (american football or Australian rules) they invite the kid to the team and as he has super strength and it turns out that the coach has some sort of power too to start fires and he is trying to kill/harm the kids on the team (I guess but basically he is trying to do something bad don't remember why) 
Kid then finds out about the coach and teach him a lesson.
There's a this scene etched in my memory when the kid comes to the school the team leader throws a football at him hoping he won't catch in and makes a mess but the kid catches it and throws the ball back even harder that's how they sign up the gut to the team. 

@Richard ...Sorry, didn't look up. :/ I came to the same conclusion. Will delete if you want.

@Richard OK, thanks. Hope it's the right one...

@Richard, Walt I never thought it would be this famous show. I thought the show was hastily made and I watched it long time ago. Most of the scenes were entirely different than I previously remember now that I watched it again. Thanks a lot.

Sounds like the season 1 episode Hothead on Smallville from 2001. From Wikipedia:

A meteor rock infused sauna endows Coach Arnold (Dan Lauria) with pyrokinesis. After several football players are caught cheating, Chloe discovers that Coach Arnold assisted the players when they cheated. Coach Arnold asks Clark to join the football team, and Clark agrees against his father's wishes. Clark confronts Coach Arnold before his first game, after Arnold attempted to kill Chloe and another football player for exposing the truth about the cheating. The coach's fury gets the better of him as he engulfs himself in flames while battling Clark.

The coach was played by Dan Lauria (Jack Arnold from The Wonder Years). Here's a clip from the ep:



